# Single reference in bibtex in foreign language

Tags: bibliographies, russian

```
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english, russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

bla bla bla bla
\cite{reference}

  \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{boo.jpg}
        \caption{booboo}
        \label{boooo}
    \end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{thebib} 
\end{document}
```

My reference file has a single reference with everything (author, name etc etc) written in Russian.

When I use the above code, everything compiles (using pdflatex) but two strange unwanted things happen.

1. The font changes to a slightly different form, not terrible but not
   the original one.
2. The figure caption is to "рис 2. booboo" . This should simply be "Fig 2. booboo". The bibliography instead of saying the word "References", says the same word in russian (cyrillic).

Comment: Currently, the issue you describe is not reproducible. Could you therefore please edit your question to include [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: `babel` takes the last language option as the main language of the document, so you could try switching the options, i.e., `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`. See page 5 of the [babel manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf).

Comment: @Marijn tried - but did not help